# check user's password from database in login route - nodejs & mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

** good part of the day! i'm just tryin to check user in login by user's e-mail, if there is such kinda e-mail than it should check the correctness of password from database, i just stopped at password-checking, help about that!

```
    const mail =  req.body.e_mail;
    const pw = req.body.password;

    RegData.findOne({e_mail: mail}, function(error, foundUser) {
        if(!error) {
            if (foundUser) {
                /*  if there is a user with correct e_mail, then check he's password: if correct send('content page'), else send('check your reg-data')   */
            } else {
                res.send("you've not been registered yet")
            }
        } else {
            res.send(error);
        }
    })
```

Comment: Please provide more detail about what's gone wrong, the code seems to be valid, I'm unsure of what your issue is here? The more detail you can provide, the more accuracy an answer will have.

Answer (score 1):

All that you have to do is to compare passwords between the provided password and the other saved in the database , but what recommended is to hash the passwords before saving it

```
const mail =  req.body.e_mail;
const pw = req.body.password;

RegData.findOne({e_mail: mail}, function(error, foundUser) {
    if(!error) {
        if (foundUser) {
            //----compare passwords-----//
         if (foundUser.password==pwd){ //password matches
               req.send('content page')
           }else{
             req.send('check your reg-data')

           }
      //---end checking password compraison
        } else {
            res.send("you've not been registered yet")
        }
    } else {
        res.send(error);
    }
})
```

I hope it is helpful!